# What the state is in a state machine that has async transition

Tags: asynchronous, state-machine

Wondering what the convention is for switching and defining states if the transition is async.

For example, say there are three states *a*, *b*, and *c*.

```
a -> b -> c
```

The two transitions call *d*, and *e*.

```
d: a -> b
e: b -> c
```

Say we are in state *a*, and then fire an event *x* to transition to state *b*.

A timeline might look like:

```
a a a a a a a a a x                     b b b b b b b
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                         d complete --^
                    |_________________|
                       intermediate
                           area
```

During that intermediate area, wondering what is the state, since the system is changing and so it may be in neither state *a* or *b*. Wondering how people typically handle this.

It seems there are 3 ways it can go:

1. It stays in state *a* until the intermediate area completes.
2. It goes to an intermediate state such as "transitioning".
3. It goes directly to state b, but there is a flag saying it can't transition out of b yet.

Comment: It is in neither state It is in transition. It is in-between.
But why would that matter? Are you polling the state from somewhere?
And what is a "async" transition?

Comment: The state will be polled, yes. And from a thoroughness standpoint I would like for there to be a clear thing happening in that in-between state.

Comment: IMHO polling a state machine is a bad idea. Why not let the state machine make calls to a callback when it enters and/or leaves a state? Then your system can react to state changes dynamically. Also it could e.g. generate events for another state machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of being "between states" during a state transition is circumvented by imposing the **run-to-completion (RTC) semantics** of processing events, which all state machine formalisms (including UML statecharts) universally assume. RTC means that a state machine must always complete processing of the previous event before it can start processing the next.

The RTC restriction comes from the fact that a state machine must always go
from one stable state configuration all the way to another stable state configuration in one *indivisible* step (RTC step). As events are the only way to interact with a state machine, a state machine cannot be observed "in-between" stable state configurations.

Also, it is very important to clearly distinguish the notion of RTC from the concept of thread preemption (see e.g., [UML state machine specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)). In particular, RTC does **not** mean that a state machine has to monopolize the CPU until the RTC step is complete. Under a preemptive multitasking kernel, an RTC step can be preempted by another thread executing on the same CPU. This is determined by the scheduling policy of the underlying multitasking kernel. When the suspended thread (running a state machine) is assigned CPU time again, it resumes its event processing from the point of preemption and, eventually, completes its event processing. As long as the preempting and the preempted threads don't share any resources, there are no concurrency hazards.

Finally, it is very important to note how the RTC semantics can be violated (often inadvertently). The first common mistake is sharing of variables or other resources between a state machine and other concurrent thread(s). In case of preemption in the middle of RTC step, these variables or resources can be accessed ("observed"), while they might not be in a consistent state.

The other frequent way to violate the RTC semantics is by *blocking* inside state machines (e.g., by calling a time delay function, semaphore, or other such OS primitive). In that case, blocking (and un-blocking) is another "back-door" way of delivering *events* to the state machine. Problem is, that such "back-door" events arrive in the middle of RTC step and thus violate the RTC semantics.

Answer (score 0):

From where I'm standing, it's pretty clear that `d` is not a transition, but a state—one which is entered by `x`, and exited by some `done_x` event.

All of your other proposed options are just hiding that fact: a state which has an internal flag is *two* states.

Languages that support `async/await`-style of asynchronous methods (like C#) exemplify this; the compiler [generates a state machine](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) for asynchronous methods.